# Identify special character in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2012

How to identify special character like below marked in blue in oracle.

[image]

these types of rows are causing an issue while we are migrating data from Oracle to MSSQL server 2012.

For migration we are using SSMA tool V5.3.0.

Comment: What is the table/database encoding in Oracle and SQL Server?

Comment: Have a look at [dump](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions063.htm#SQLRF00635)

Comment: You need to define two terms. First what do you mean by "identify"? That may mean many things. Second, which characters are "special"? Do you know which characters are causing an issue? Is it all the characters with a code above 127?

Comment: by "identify" I mean a script which can list down these type of characters. As attached, the character shown on sql developer as '[]' when click it, it shows as '?', not sure whether it's above 127.